# Django: authenticate based on an object's properties using class-based views

Tags: django, django-authentication, django-class-based-views

Let's say my app is like a forum, but that each post has a group of people which may see it.

```
SecretPost(Model):
    can_see = myapp.main.models.GroupOfUsers()
```

I want to write a view which restricts users' access to these posts, and I'd prefer to use decorators, since that's how I've been handling access control everywhere else.

```
SecretPostView(DetailView):
    """Can only be seen by members of its group"""

    @method_decorator(part_of_its_group)
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(SecretPostView, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

But when `dispatch()` is called, I don't know anything about the object. Is there a good/idiomatic way to restrict user access after the object has already been retrieved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access `self` inside the method decorator, so you *do* have access to the current object calling `self.get_object()`.

Anyway, if you are only using this behavior on generic views, you're probably better off creating a mixin that implement the `dispatch` method (or could be the `get_object` method) and does the check there, for example (using a little of imagination since idk how your groups are defined, maybe you are using django.contrib.auth groups):

```
class GroupRestrictionMixin(object):
    group_field = 'group'

    def dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.request = request
        self.args = args
        self.kwargs = kwargs

        obj_group = getattr(self.get_object(), self.group_field)
        user_groups = request.user.groups

        if obj_group not in user_groups:
            raise PermissionDenied

        return super(GroupRestrictionMixin, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Then you can create any view that needs that behavior using your mixin:

```
class SecretPostView(GroupRestrictionMixin, DetailView):
    pass
```

Idk if it's what you would call "idiomatic", but that's the easier way that comes to mind to keep it simple and reusable.

**EDIT:** the request, args and kwargs must be setted here so the `get_object` method haves access to them. It gets a little uglier (you gotta repeat some code that's on the base `dispatch` method), but still works :F

Comment: Hmm... when I call `get_object` within the `dispatch` method, I get an error that my object doesn't have a `kwargs` attribute.

Comment: I made an edit a while ago explaining why. I wasn't aware of it, but I tested out by myself and found out that the dispatch method is the one that asigns the `request`, `args` and `kwargs` attributes to the generic view.