# Allowing views and template content to certain groups

Tags: django

I am working on a project where i need to distinguish between two groups (and admin):

- Therapists
- Patients

When the users login, i want to easily set the views according to what they have permission to see and able to do, also in the templates. What is the best-practice in this particular use-case? I have read about the [PermissionMixin](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#django.contrib.auth.models.PermissionsMixin) which is proposed in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15181622/django-authenticate-based-on-an-objects-properties-using-class-based-views) question. So far i have considered using that method proposed along with a method to inside my template to change the content according to the group. Is this the way to go?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you create the matching permission groups, it's as easy as decorating your view like :

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import permission_required

@permission_required('foo.doctor')
def patients_registry_view(request):
    ...
```

If you create a larger project where most of the views are somehow restricted, mixins are the way to go.

[The documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/auth/default/) gives in-dept coverage of this topic, I strongly recommend taking a look.

Comment: In my perspective it seems that the mixins are somewhat more convenient to use, or am i completely wrong? Furthermore how do i handle the actual templates, hence content should only be viewed if the user is from a certain group.